# Quartz.properties

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I developed an EAR using Quartz API. I have put my quartz.properties file in the classpath`(WEB-INF/classes` in war). Added following lines to `web.xml` file

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>config-file</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/quartz.properties</param-value>
</context-param>
```

But Quartz still loads the default properties file from the `quartz.jar`

Comment: I am using ServletContextListner to initialize Quartz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that `config-file` should be a servlet parameter, not a context parameter, like the example given at http://www.openscope.net/2010/02/05/quartz-scheduled-jobs/.  See also quartz docs on `QuartzInitializationServlet` [here](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/api/org/quartz/ee/servlet/QuartzInitializerServlet.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try with /quartz.properties instead of /WEB-INF/classes/quartz.properties.

Answer (score 0):

The param-value you had inserted is interpreted as a string, not a path.
I believe that upon initialization, the config file is being searched in "WEB-INF\classes" folder... whereas you meant something like "\webapps\\WEB-INF\classes.
(would help to add logs,at least for the initialization part...)

since the resource  "WEB-INF\classes\quartz.properties" isn't found, the default quartz.properties is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error between maven dependencies

erase from your pom.xml this dependencie

```
<!-- Quartz spring-support -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-support</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

And relaunch...